# PIL.Image to cv2: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am using the pyautogui library to take a screenshot, which gets stored as PIL.Image.Image.
When I try to use cv2's cvtColor() function to convert it, I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Here is my code:

```
img = pyautogui.screenshot(0, 0, 500, 500)
print(type(img))    #<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
img_rgb = numpy.array(img)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

What is my mistake here, and how could I convert the image as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used the library, but from the error it gave out

try

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img_rgb), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

EDIT :

This is my test code which works fine

```
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 500, 500)) 
    #tested on impossible resolution as well, but the library still handles it. 
print(type(img))  #<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
img_rgb = np.array(img) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("img",img_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: cv2.Umat() is functionally equivalent to np.float32(), so theoretically, this should work

Comment: I tried this, and I'm getting the following TypeError:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Image'

Comment: Okkay, I read the docs and tried to recreate your problem, and it works fine for me.

in your line 1 `img = pyautogui.screenshot(0, 0, 500, 500)` try `img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 500, 500))`, because there might be some other keyword it thinks your calling instead

Comment: Im adding my test code to the EDIT, see if it helps

Comment: Are you running it on a pi camera? or your computer? There might be a resolution issue with region size

Comment: Let me know if the region keyword solves it, I'll edit my answer for future users then

Comment: This did solve it, although I have to admit I was using a workaround with a different imaging library, and looking back at this now I am having trouble recreating my original error myself. Thank you for this solution though.